# Question with "if" vs. "do,did"

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

Is the following grammatical ?

> If he didn't come to the work is to be ill.

Does "he didn't come to the work" here mean "he is ill" ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to say? Neither of those are clear, or grammatical.

Comment: I mean : "he didn't come to the work" plays role as subject.

Comment: Does the fact he didn't come to the work mean he is ill ?

Comment: that one works for me, better than the versions in the question. Though you still need to lose 'the work'. It's just 'work'. Possibly also add 'that'. "Does the fact that he didn't come to work mean he is ill?"

Comment: Does it mean that "the fact that he didn't come to work " plays role as the free relative clause ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no grammarian, I've no idea what a 'free relative clause' is. I'm just a native Br E speaker.

Comment: I did an edit. Please comment me if it had changed the content of your Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If he didn't come to the work is to be ill.

Nope, not grammatical, and not natural sounding either.

> The fact that he didn't come to work means he's ill.

is in my opinion the clearest way to express what you want to say, or, if you really want to be conditional:

> He wouldn't come to work if he's ill.

The below two are also correct, and directly use "he didn't come to work" as a "subject" - but could be a tiny bit jarring or potentially confusing unless someone is paying good attention to you or reading the text.

> That he didn't come to work means he's ill.
>
> Not coming to work means he's ill.

You might also hear this, I'm pretty sure it's ungrammatical but I've heard similar things many times.

> Him not coming to work means he's ill.

Comment: you nailed it. Except for one thing if the sentence is to mean that not coming to work indicates that he is ill, the "conditional" would be "he would come to work unless he was ill". The way you stated the "conditional", it allows for other reasons for not coming.